# Como ejecutar dos scripts de Python a la vez

Tags: python, api, hilos, twitter

Estoy programando un bot de Twitter. Tengo dos códigos python separados. Ambos funcionan con un while true constante, que hace que el bot esté permanentemente trabajando. En uno de los códigos se postean tweets cada media hora y en el otro código se responden tweets si el bot es mencionado, cada 5 segundos. Quiero unir ambos scripts en un sólo código, pero no puedo hacerlo manteniendo el time sleep de cada código. Si uno ambos códigos en un mismo while, el bot comparte time sleep.

El código que me gustaría unir para ejecutar a la vez es el siguiente:

```
while True:
    api = create_bot()
    reply(api)
    print("Waiting for mentions...")
    time.sleep(3)

while True:
    api = create_bot()
    status = extract_status("texto.txt")
    print(status)

    try:
        api.update_status(status)
        print("Successfully posted.")
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)

    #reply(api)
    #print("Waiting for mentions...")
    time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: muestra algo de código para que alguien te pueda ayudar a solucionar tu problema de una mejor manera.

Comment: Te toca aprender a usar `async` o `threading`. Google es tu mejor amigo para esto.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más básica de lograr tu objetivo es cambiar un poco la forma de ver el problema. Tienes una tarea que se debe ejecutar cada 5 seg. y una segunda que se debe ejecutar cada 30 min, esto puedes simplificarlo a ejecutar una tarea **t1** cada 5 seg. y una tarea **t2** por cada `(30*60)/5` veces que se ejecute `t1`, esto debido a que 30 minutos tienen `60*30` segundos y quieres contar cuantas veces se ejecuta una tarea que ocurre cada 5 segundos.

```py
contador_t1 = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    contador_t1 += 1
    ejecutar_t1()

    if contador_t1 == (30*60)/5
        contador_t1 = 0
        ejecutar_t2()
```

El problema con este enfoque es que la tarea **t1** va crear una desface cada vez que se ejecute, es decir que un paso en el ciclo while cuando solo se ejecuta la tarea **t1** va ser igual al tiempo de ejecución de **t1** más los 5 segundos que se suspende el proceso por la función sleep, esto va crear posiblemente un retraso de igual magnitud al tiempo que le toma a la función **t1** ejecutarse.

Si tu función **t1** no tarda demasiado en finalizar entonces el retraso puede ser despreciable e ignorable, realmente aún cuando solo se tuviera un sola función que se ejecutara cada **n** segundos mediante `sleep`, este comportamiento raramente va ser preciso por temas del algoritmo de planificación apropiativos que usan los sistemas operativos.

Una forma tal vez más correcta pero que tiende a demandar más conocimientos y tener cuidado con ciertos problemas, es a través del manejo de concurrencia. El término de concurrencia lo vas a ver definido de maneras ligeramente distintas pero todos tratan de llegar al mismo punto que es intentar realizar tareas al mismo tiempo sin necesariamente llegar a ser al mismo tiempo(paralelas). Las bondades de la concurrencia se ven reflejadas en procesos más cerrados en cuanto a lapsos de tiempo, por ejemplo las conexiones a los servidores de google, la diferencia entre el tiempo de llegada entre dos o más peticiones estan definidas posiblemente en ordenes muy pequeñas como nanosegundos, es aquí donde un modelo  de concurrencia es obligatorio y no basta con un modelo de un solo hilo síncrono como el que se vio reflejada en nuestra primera solución.

Para lograr atacar la concurrencia existen varios enfoques como programas multiprocesadores, multihilos, modelos asíncronos basados en eventos, etc. Es un tema bastante complejo y no tan estricto en el sentido de que generalmente los sistemas no se van por un solo enfoque y combinan varios de ellos. En tu caso bastaría usar hilos o theadings.

```py
import threading
import time

def t1():
    time.sleep(5) # Dormir 5 segundos
    # resto de instrucciones


def t2():
   time.sleep(60*30)
   # resto de instrucciones


hilo_1 = threading.Thread(target=t1)
hilo_2 = threading.Thread(target=t2)

hilo_1.start()
hilo_2.start()
```

Tomar la decisión de que debes utilizar para atacar un problema de concurrencia es más complicado de lo que pareciera y es dependiente incluso del lenguaje de programación. Está última solución sobrepasa el problema que teniamos del retraso, de una manera muy flexible podriamos decir que una tarea se ejecutara cada 5 seg y otra cada 30m sin contratiempos.

Te recomiendo leer un poco más sobre los hilos en python y los problemas de concurrencia, esta página tiene algunas muy buenas entradas sobre [Concurrencias](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/) e [Hilos.](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)